# Issue in getting Android ACTION_TIME_CHANGED Broadcast

Tags: android, datetime, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

Need to get a broadcast when user changes `Date/Time` manually but not when the system updates `Date/Time`. I am using `ACTION_TIME_CHANGED` and it works but it notifies even for normal Date/Time changes (i.e., without user intervention).

Please suggest how to handle this issue.

Thanks

Comment: without user intervention means what exactly you want to do.....please explain your GUI.

Comment: Share your Code, from that we can Discuss

Comment: @Anil OP wants to get notified when the user changes the date/time (using settings page) but NOT when the system changes the date/time (for example, by synchronizing with a network time server or a mobile operator's time server).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think it is possible to differentiate between the two.

Comment: I tried to do that before some days in my application but there is no guarantee to work this event. It will works irregularly sometimes but more times it not works. There are only 2-3% chances to invoke this event.So avoided to use this event.

Comment: thanks everyone for the inputs